# Can't reproduce threading deadlock with MethodImplOptions.Synchronized

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

I'm trying to reproduce some deadlock with only MethodImplOptions.Synchronized method notation:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Lab_01
{

    class Program1
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        static void Resource1(int starterIndex, bool startNext = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resource1 is used ({0})", starterIndex);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (startNext)
            {
                Resource2(starterIndex, false);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Resource1 is free ({0})", starterIndex);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        static void Resource2(int starterIndex, bool startNext = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resource2 is used ({0})", starterIndex);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (startNext)
            {
                Resource1(starterIndex, false);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Resource2 is free ({0})", starterIndex);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Locker locker1 = new Locker();
            Locker locker2 = new Locker();

            new Thread(delegate()
            {
                Resource1(0);
            }).Start();
            new Thread(delegate()
            {
                Resource2(1);
            }).Start();

        }
    }
}
```

What I expect is

1. 1st thread is started and only the Resource1 method is locked, it waits for 1 sec
2. While 1st thread is sleeping (this 1 second) 2nd thread is started and it locks the 2nd resource (Resource2). It sleeps for 1 sec.
3. The thread, which ends the sleep first, say 1st thread, want to lock the 2nd resource, but it can't because it's already locked, and can't be freed, because the second thread is in the same situation (it wants to lock Recource1, but it's already locked). In one word, the regular deadlock situation.

But when I start it it doesn't lock itself and I'm getting this output:

```
C:\Users\ginz\C#\19-\Lab_01\Lab_01\bin\Debug>Lab_01.exe
Resource1 is used (0)
Resource2 is used (0)
Resource2 is free (0)
Resource1 is free (0)
Resource2 is used (1)
Resource1 is used (1)
Resource1 is free (1)
Resource2 is free (1)
```

So, the second thread is started only when the first thread has come to the end, but I think it should start much earlier. Why is this?

I know this behavior can be simply reproduced by using `lock` keyword, but in my case that's inappropriate way:

```
            Object obj1 = new Object(), obj2 = new Object();

            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                lock (obj1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    lock (obj2)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
            })).Start();

            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                lock (obj2)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    lock (obj1)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
           })).Start();
```

Could you please help me in this situation?

Thanks in advance,
Dmitry

Comment: Sounds to me you've completely missed the point of the homework assignment.  Review your course material for hints what kind of locking MethodImplOptions.Synchronized does.  It should mention something like `lock(this)`, that requires an instance method.  Not a static method like you're using.

Comment: Huh, surely you're right.